# setdiff for a list of dataframes without using a loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data.frames which are indexed by year and I want to take the `setdiff` between a column in these nested data.frames and a seperate vector.

For a list of data.frames `a`, and a vector `b`. Right now I'm looping over the elements

```
for (i in a) {
    missing_values = setdiff(x = b, y = i$col1)
    print(missing_values)                            #this has what I want
    store_values[i$year[[1]]] = list(missing_values) #actually this doesn't work as expected but not sure why
     }
setdiff(x = b, y = a$'2010'$col1) #returns what I want for 1 data.frame
```

Is there a way to do this aside from a loop?

```
store_values
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] NA
```

Not sure if sample data is needed for this problem, but I can provide some if requested.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 4))
colnames(df) <- c('col1', 'year')
df$col1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
df$year <- c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2011)
df <- split(df, df$year)

b <- c('a', 'g')
setdiff(x = b, y = df$`2010`$col1) #g

store_values <- ls()
for (i in df){
  missing_values <- setdiff(x = b, y = i$col1)
  print(missing_values)                              # good
  store_values[i$year[[1]]] <- list(missing_values)  # no good
}
```

Comment: are you sure `a$'2010'$col1` returns what you want? Anyway you should provide a and b to make it reproducible,..

Comment: @BigDataScientist added some sample data

Comment: Splitting df by year is a rather bad idea, in my opinion. Now you have year stored as both a number and as a string (the name of each df), and have to go through contortions like a loop or lapply here and in every subsequent step)... With data.table, you could do `fsetdiff(CJ(col1 = b, year = unique(DT$year)), DT)` or similarly with dplyr's setdiff along with expand.grid.

Comment: @Frank never really used `data.table`s, do I have to change `df` to a `data.table` in this case?

Comment: Yeah. With dplyr, it should be something like `setdiff(expand.grid(col1 = b, year = unique(df$year)), df)` I guess (though I haven't used that), without needing to convert to anything first.

Comment: You're so right. `lapply` is my new worst enemy. What a disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lapply`:

```
res <- lapply(df, FUN = function(x) {
  setdiff(x = b, y = x$col1)
})
res

$`2010`
[1] "g"

$`2011`
[1] "a" "g"
```

Comment: Indeed. It even serves you the output format you want (if im not mistaken) as its default ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to just keep everything in a data.frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = data_frame(col1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
                year = c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2011))
b <- c('a', 'g')

df %>% group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(missing_vals = list(setdiff(b, col1))) %>% 
    unnest()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>    year missing_vals
#>   <dbl>        <chr>
#> 1  2010            g
#> 2  2011            a
#> 3  2011            g
```

which in base R might translate to

```r
do.call(rbind, 
        apply(aggregate(col1 ~ year, df, 
                        function(x){setdiff(b, x)}), 
              1, data.frame))
#>   year col1
#> 1 2010    g
#> 2 2011    a
#> 3 2011    g
```

From this point, it's easy to do further operations grouped by `year` or `col1`.